# SQLite- Storing multiple values in same column

Tags: sqlite, append

In `SQLite` , How would you store the information like this:

```
id       name         groups
1        xyz          one,two
2        abc          one
3        lmn          two,three
```

The `groups` column may multiple entries. How can we store like that?
The main thing is the multiple values are should be appended.

Comment: Maybe store them as a JSON array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand it correctly but why not store it as [delimited string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter)? Something like string1;string2;string3..or use comma instead of semi-colon like you already posted.

Just fetch the row, append the data followed by your delimiter and update the record. When you need the individual entries, just split the string using your delimiter.